# Difference in Timestamp in PHP and Java

Tags: java, php, android

I try to generate timestamp in PHP and Java(Android). Both needs to be same. But I am getting a difference of 3000+ between the time stamps. Please check the code below!

JAVA :

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

Php :

```
$time2 = time();
```

Comment: Well, work out which is correct and which isn't. I like epochconverter.com for this purpose... You say they're "3000+" out - what's the *exact* difference? Presumably one of these is on a mobile device and one is on a server... have you checked the time settings on both?

Comment: exactly one is in mobile and other is in server. server is running in php. The timestamp generated by php is in sync with epochconverter.com. but the value that comes from mobile is wrong. Is there anything wrong in that java code?

Comment: No, but it sounds like the device's clock may be incorrect. You shouldn't *rely* on a client-generated value if this is for licensing etc, btw - the user could always change the clock manually.

Comment: hmm.. well my requirement is to get the unix timestamp only. In my mobile the time is different so I think that is causing the difference in timestamp. But say in my mac(localhost server) I have the same time as my mobile. but the timestamp generated is the one in sync with epoch!! y its possible in mac and not in android?

Comment: Ensure that you are generating timestamps in the same timezone. When in doubt, force it all to GMT when passing data between client/server. GMT is *usually* immune to being screwed up by DST or otherwise incorrect timezone settings. If the GMT times differ, then you've screwed up the hardware clock on one or both devices.

Comment: hmm.. I think System.currentTimeMillis() will get me the current time in mobile and java.util.Date(); gets me based on GMT. Solved it. Thanks :)

Comment: @GeoPaul: Nope, that's not the right solution. `System.currentTimeMillis()` should always give you the milliseconds since the *UTC* epoch.

Comment: $Jon Skeet : I tried it and got that difference. Please check that in your code

Comment: @GeoPaul: Your Android system clock is just wrong, honestly. `System.currentTimeMillis` does *not* depend on the time zone.

Answer (score -1):

System.currentTimeMillis() will get me the current time in mobile and java.util.Date(); gets me based on GMT. Solved it.

Comment: No, `System.currentTimeMills()` should *not* be affected by time zone.

Comment: Please check it in your code. I tried it and found the difference. System.currentTimeMillis() will get it based on the time on your System Clock.. ie the android clock!!

Comment: Well yes - but still based on UTC. It's *not* affected by time zone, but it *is* affected by the system clock... as will the PHP code of course.